# Is there a program that can expand a hard drive partition by adding online storage?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, storage

I want to enlarge a local partition by adding online storage but I know no such provider.  I use Win 10 and Ubuntu 15.10. On Ubuntu I only have 15 GB left on my largest partition. Is it possible to install some program that will enable my partition to grow larger, e.g. like dropbox but actually making the partition larger locally in the file system?

Or a way to "merge" a USB drive and an existing partition so that I get one large partition?

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1,6G   11M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/sdb1       102G   83G   15G  86% /
tmpfs           7,8G  103M  7,7G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1,6G   72K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda1       932G  445G  488G  48% /media/dac/Seagate Backup Plus Drive1
tmpfs           1,6G  8,0K  1,6G   1% /run/user/112
```

Ideally, I want `/dev/sdb1` to grow to 1 TB or so.

Comment: You may extend your partition provided your primary partition is using LVM2. However extending it with a USB volume would be highly risky and may corrupt your whole system! It would be more sensible deleting files you don't need, and move documents to the mounted USB.

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister I run Ubuntu 15.10 and when I cleaned the drive, it was still taking about 80 GB just the system and apps, and I don't have many large apps. Maybe I have a large project installation somewhere that I didn't delete.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Partition Master

download (free version): http://www.partition-tool.com/download.htm

Comment: OP's not asking to resize partitions to allocate more space. Partition Master can't enlarge a partition using cloud or usb.